# Redirect to checkout after adding item to cart magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, cart

I'm using Magento 1.92. I want two buttons on product page,one is the default "add to cart"buttons;the other button,"proceed to checkout",Redirect  to checkout  after adding item to cart.

```
public function afterAddToCart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $response = $observer->getResponse();

    $response->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage'));
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setNoCartRedirect(true);
}
```

use the Observer above and it can direct to checkout page.But I also want to keep the default add to cart button,so the code is:

```
public function afterAddToCart(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam(‘checkout’)) {
        $response = $observer->getResponse();
        $response->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl(‘checkout/onepage’));
        Mage::getSingleton(‘checkout/session’)->setNoCartRedirect(true);
    }
}
```

the button with "checkout" in the url direct to checkout page,the button without "checkout" in the url add product to cart.
I'm stuck here.how to get the url of "add to cart" button?what if the product has custom options?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: There's a solution here:http://www.magecorner.com/bypass-cart-and-go-to-checkout/ ,which can bypass shopping cart successfully.The author also explains how to have one button for default “add to cart” and one button for “direct checkout” in comments,but I don't know how to implement this.

Comment: Well, give it a go, we're not gonna do it for you :)

Comment: yeah,thank you for the reply,if i know how,i don't need to ask the question here.

Comment: SO isn't a teaching portal, neither are we a "step-by-step" / "how-to" - Give  it a try and if you run into errors we'll still be here if you can't solve it.

Comment: okey.actually i tried.